# IoT Hub client on Emb Linux returns SSL channel closed when send_event_async

Tags: linux, azure, ssl, raspberry-pi, iot

I am using a RaspberryPi with Ubuntu Mate and I am trying to run samples from [Iot Hub Client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python). I builded the library for Ubuntu doumented [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/doc/python-devbox-setup.md). I also builded the Windows version just for test and it worked fine with the exact code. The error I get on Unix, when using IoTHubClient.send_event_async is:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
IoT Hub for Python SDK Version: 1.0.17
Starting the IoT Hub Python sample...
    Protocol MQTT
    Connection string=HostName=<hub name>.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=BananaPi_rasp;SharedAccessKey=<access kwy>
Info: IoT Hub SDK for C, version 1.0.17
IoTHubClient sending 2 messages
IoTHubClient.send_event_async accepted message [0] for transmission to IoT Hub.
Error: Time:Tue Jan 10 02:21:25 2017 File:/home/pi/azure-iot-sdks/c/iothub_client/src/iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c Func:mqtt_operation_complete_callback Line:951 Connection Not Accepted: 0x5: Not Authorized
Error: Time:Tue Jan 10 02:21:25 2017 File:/home/pi/azure-iot-sdks/c/c-utility/src/tlsio_openssl.c Func:decode_ssl_received_bytes Line:654 SSL channel closed in decode_ssl_received_bytes.
Error: Time:Tue Jan 10 02:21:25 2017 File:/home/pi/azure-iot-sdks/c/c-utility/src/tlsio_openssl.c Func:on_underlying_io_bytes_received Line:709 Error in decode_ssl_received_bytes.
```

I have tried to fix it by setting the system time and checking out the certificate specifications:
I tried to "ping" the server to see if I can connect to it with:

> openssl s_client -connect .azure-devices.net:8883

I get:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = IE, O = Baltimore, OU = CyberTrust, CN = Baltimore CyberTrust Root
......
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGcjCCBFqgAwIBAgITWgABtrN..........<etire certificate>...
......
SSL handshake has read 3677 bytes and written 531 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
.....
Protocol  : TLSv1.2
Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Session-ID: B0010000E7F6C6ADDC09A37DC7C618C4F4522528E20C8AD6E08DCB5B302101D2
Session-ID-ctx:
Start Time: 1483986649
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
read:errno=0
```

From I can understand all looks good.

I tried also to check the certificate validity:

> openssl x509 -in /usr/lib/ssl/certs/Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.pem

I get:

```
  ........
  Validity
            Not Before: May 12 18:46:00 2000 GMT
            Not After : May 12 23:59:00 2025 GMT
    ......
```

So it seems OK,
Everything looks fine here but still I get that error.
Does anybody has any idea what might be wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience on this which may help you.

First, make sure system time is correct on your RaspberryPi.

Then print your device password to see if se field is correct:
in umqtt/src/mqtt_codec.c constructConnPayload()
mqttOptions->password is look like this:
SharedAccessSignature sr=IoT-xxxx.azure-devices.net/devices/xxxx&sig=xxxxxxxxxxx&se=1484812561&skn=

If your see se=3600 or not equal to (current UTC time +3600), then your situation is the same as mine.

How to fix it:
in iothub_client/src/iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c SendMqttConnectMsg()
case DEVICE_KEY:
modify size_t secSinceEpoch = (size_t)(difftime(get_time(NULL), EPOCH_TIME_T_VALUE) + 0);
to size_t secSinceEpoch = (size_t)(time(NULL));

EPOCH_TIME_T_VALUE is 0 on my system, so (difftime(get_time(NULL), EPOCH_TIME_T_VALUE) + 0) should be equal to get_time(NULL).
But difftime seems not working on my system so secSinceEpoch is always 0.
Finally I just use time(NULL) for it.

I spent days for this solution. Hope it can help you.